# How to disable connection to my database from root user?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I just want to disable to connect with **root** on my database from remote just for security concern. I'm sure there is a way but I couldn't find it on google or other places.
I must add that I want to still be able to use **root** with **SSH** to create tables.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic. Maybe you should ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what do you mean by "connect with root on my database from remote" then, if you want to be able to connect with root via ssh? root user in MySQL? it's like that by default, that you can't connect with root user not from localhost.

Comment: thks to reply, personnally i can connect right now with ssh in mariaDb and can make all change, drop tables on any database and even drop databases, like any root user. i do from my laptop outside my house by connection with 'root'. Are you sure it is by default ? i will try on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ i didn't know this website

Comment: `ssh` adds a wrinkle to what is considered "default".